# MongoDB stable?

Tags: php, mongodb

So i am starting to make this new app that will be a software as a service (SAAS), I have been looking at MongoDB but after reading some posts i get the impression that its not stable where you have to run the repair command alot and its easy to lose data.

So with the release of 2.0 are these issues still about?

To note: the app is not a forum but it will do simler sort of things that the database is needed for like users, posts, and others sorts of information, is a NoSQL the right type of DB for me or should i just go with MySQL? its also coded in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should write "simple" "helloworld" application(blog with user registration) with Mongo.
It's very different from relational DB, so you will see the difference yourself.